# 8x8 square with no adjacent numbers summing to a prime

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, primes, latin-square

Can you fill a 8x8 grid with numbers from 1 to 8 such that:

- Every number occurs exactly once in each row and in each column (Latin square).
- No two adjacent (horizontally or vertically) numbers sum to a prime.

Good luck!

Comment: This seems more like a search than a puzzle. I wonder how many of the 108776032459082956800 possible Latin squares would satisfy this?

Comment: @Jay the second constraint forces serious limitations on the structure of the square. Once you realize this, you will see that there are not that many options. The final solution has a lot of structure and beauty.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I see there is some strategy in building it

Comment: By using constraint programming, I found that there are 4,223,584 solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this works:

> ```
> 7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2
> 5 3 1 8 6 4 2 7
> 3 1 8 6 4 2 7 5
> 1 8 6 4 2 7 5 3
> 8 6 4 2 7 5 3 1
> 6 4 2 7 5 3 1 8
> 4 2 7 5 3 1 8 6
> 2 7 5 3 1 8 6 4
> ```

The adjacent number pairs are restricted to

> (7,5), (5,3), (3,1), (1,8), (8,6), (6,4), (4,2), (2,7)

where each pair sums to

> either an even number (greater than 2) or 9, all of which are composite.

Note that it is necessary to

> minimize the boundary between an even and an odd number

because

> the only possible odd sums are 9 (allowing four pairs) and 15 (only allowing (7,8)).

Comment: Very nice. I didn't even consider this solution.

Comment: Actually, the solution is easily generalised to any $n\times n$ square for $n\geqslant6$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one:

> 7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2
>  
>  1 7 5 3 6 4 2 8
>  
>  3 1 7 5 4 2 8 6
>  
>  5 3 1 7 2 8 6 4
>  
>  4 6 8 2 7 1 3 5
>  
>  2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7
>  
>  8 2 4 6 3 5 7 1
>  
>  6 8 2 4 5 7 1 3

Note that for any permutation of the first 4 columns there are 6 matching permutations of the last 4 that give rise to another solution. And similar for rows. So this is actually a family of solutions.

Comment: Nice. This is the solution I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy using a constraint solver.
For example Minizinc language and then using Gecode solver:

```
include "alldifferent.mzn";


int: N = 8;
array[1..N,1..N] of var 1..N: p;
set of int: not_primes = array2set([4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]);


constraint forall(n in 1..N)(
  alldifferent([p[n,g] |g in 1..N]) /\ alldifferent([p[g,n] |g in 1..N])
 );
constraint forall(n in 1..N, g in 1..(N-1)) (
    p[n,g]+p[n,g+1] in not_primes
);
constraint forall(n in 1..N, g in 1..(N-1)) (
    p[g,n]+p[g+1,n] in not_primes
);


output  [show_int(1,p[i,j])++
  if j == N then
    if i != N then "\n"
    else " " endif
  else " " endif
  | i,j in 1..N ] ++ ["\n"];
```

There are millions of solutions. (I didn't wait.).

```
8 2 4 6 3 1 7 5
6 4 2 8 1 7 5 3
3 5 7 1 8 2 4 6
1 7 5 3 6 4 2 8
5 3 1 7 2 8 6 4
7 1 3 5 4 6 8 2
2 8 6 4 5 3 1 7
4 6 8 2 7 5 3 1
----------
1 5 3 7 2 6 8 4
7 3 1 5 4 2 6 8
5 1 7 3 6 8 4 2
3 7 5 1 8 4 2 6
6 2 4 8 1 5 7 3
2 6 8 4 5 1 3 7
4 8 6 2 7 3 1 5
8 4 2 6 3 7 5 1
----------
7 3 1 5 4 8 6 2
3 7 5 1 8 2 4 6
5 1 3 7 2 6 8 4
1 5 7 3 6 4 2 8
8 4 2 6 3 5 7 1
4 6 8 2 7 1 3 5
2 8 6 4 5 7 1 3
6 2 4 8 1 3 5 7
```

Comment: I don't think the code is right. On the bottom left corner of the first grid, 2 and 3 are adjacent.

Comment: The constraints for the last row (n = N and g < N) and last column (g = N and n < N) were omitted.

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt. I've corrected the code.

Answer (score -2):

The following Latin square meets the requirements you have set.

> [image: ![Jan18]

Comment: You really should learn to use something easier to read than a picture of hand drawing.